# Unable to establish connection to remote: spawn ENOTDIR

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am using VS code Remote-SSH to connect to the remote machines to modify the files. Currently upon trying to connect the Remote-SSH: Connect to host. I get the error message," Could not establish connection to "": spawn ENOTDIR.

The full error log is as follows:

```
[09:29:43.567] Log Level: 2
[09:29:43.568] remote-ssh@0.65.1
[09:29:43.568] darwin arm64
[09:29:43.569] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+xps", attempt 1
[09:29:43.569] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[09:29:43.569] "remote.SSH.sshPath": undefined
[09:29:43.569] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": undefined
[09:29:43.569] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[09:29:43.569] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[09:29:43.569] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[09:29:43.569] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[09:29:43.570] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[09:29:43.570] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[09:29:43.570] SSH Resolver called for host: xps
[09:29:43.570] Setting up SSH remote "xps"
[09:29:43.571] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/jf/rk7bz0g157x7yd5q_f726zyr0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-xps-install.lock
[09:29:43.592] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/taramishra/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-xps-f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8-0.65.1/data.json
[09:29:43.592] Using commit id "f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8" and quality "stable" for server
[09:29:43.594] Install and start server if needed
[09:29:43.595] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[09:29:43.596] Finding installed ssh failed: spawn ENOTDIR
[09:29:43.599] Resolver error: Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:407:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:557:9)
    at /Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:141985
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at k (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:141906)
    at I (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:141857)
    at /Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:145959
    at _ (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:146024)
    at C (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:141636)
    at Object.t.getSshCommandPath (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:144744)
    at Function.create (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:262426)
    at async Object.t.tryInstallWithLocalServer (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:387852)
    at async /Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:293749
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:407055)
    at async /Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:387177
    at async N (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:383945)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:386804)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:297790)
    at async /Users/taramishra/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:127:110485
[09:29:43.601] ------
```

I have tried to reinstall the Remote-Development packages and also cleared up the .vscode-server files in the remote. They do not seem to help.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, I had this problem with my VSCode just today as well! For me, it just stopped working today all of a sudden (may have something to do with the latest VScode update). The problem is that VSCode can no longer find your ssh program, which it was previously able to do.

1. Go to your Remote-SSH preferences (`cmd + ,` and search for `remote-ssh`).
2. Find the field labeled `Remote.SSH: Path`. Right now it's probably blank for you because VSCode used to find the executable by itself.
3. Input the absolute path to your `ssh` executable. If you are unsure of the path, you can run `which ssh` in your terminal and copy the path it prints out.
4. Save your settings, and retry the ssh. Worked for me!